# CakePHP UnitTests colours in Git Bash

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit

Is it possible to show colours in Git Bash when running PHPUnit Tests within a CakePHP application? See screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: This is a windows machine? What OS exactly? I am not sure if that is easily solvable on Win.

Comment: I'm using Windows as OS, exactly (Windows 7 to be precise). But the colours are working in CMD, with PHPUnit Tests, but not in GitBash. And to run cakephp tests, I need to run them in git bash, can't get them working in CMD.